# My mouseEvent is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm not sure if I'm using mouse Event right since it's my first time using it. What I'm trying to do is, if I hover over one of my drawn objects, I want to display a blurb saying which city it is, the population and an image of their downtown etc.

```
<script>
function startCanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  //first circle
  var one = c.getContext("2d");
  //second circle
  var two = c.getContext("2d");
  //third cirle
  var three = c.getContext("2d");
  //fourth circle
  var four = c.getContext("2d");
  //fifth cirle
  var five = c.getContext("2d");
  // new image
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
    //draw a circle
    one.beginPath();
    one.arc(180, 90, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    one.closePath();
    one.fill();
    two.beginPath();
    two.arc(155, 138, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    two.closePath();
    two.fill();
    three.beginPath();
    three.arc(160, 180, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    three.closePath();
    three.fill();
    four.beginPath();
    four.arc(257, 210, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    four.closePath();
    four.fill();
    five.beginPath();
    five.arc(238, 235, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    five.closePath();
    five.fill();
  };
  image.src = 'denmark.jpg';
  //function hover over circle one, give alert
  var startlisten = new mouseEvent.Listen({canvas:document.getElementById('myCanvas')});
  var circle = new mouseEvent.Register({
    type: 'mouseover',
    name: 'test',
    x: [180],
    y: [90],
    callback: function () { alert('this is a test'); }
  });
  startlisten.add(test);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startCanvas()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600";">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using some kind of framework or library?

Comment: im not using any framework or libraray

Comment: where is the code that defines »mouseEvent« ?

Comment: Where did you read about `new mouseEvent.Register` function? I don't think it's a part of native JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this code:

```
var startlisten = new mouseEvent.Listen({canvas:document.getElementById('myCanvas')});
var circle = new mouseEvent.Register({
    type: 'mouseover',
    name: 'test',
    x: [180],
    y: [90],
    callback: function () { alert('this is a test'); }
});
```

That isn't native JS. Try this instead:

```
c.addEventListener( // Since your code defince `c` as `document.getElementById("myCanvas")`
    'mouseover',
    function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        alert('this is a test');
    }
);
```

Comment: how do i make it work if i use circle one. it doesn't seem to work for me, i've try this.